# Python SQL variable like search

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to run this query - SELECT count (*) FROM [WorkflowTotals01] where [E1] like '%wfname%'

The wfname is a variable that's populated from another list. We need to use a like command, but am unable to figure out how to use like with a variable.

Comment: Not clear where you want to use `wfname` as variable. If in sql then please mention the which DBMS because it changes for each one of them like in sql server you can do `like '%'+@wfname+'%'`. If in the code then concatenate the string with variable.

Comment: What rdbms is this ? Inferring from the python tag, if you're creating a sql string then cant you just create the statement with concatenating your variable `wfname` ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is your query string that you should use to pass into your db cursor. Pass the variable as an argument into your script. or you can just set it

Pass

```
query = "SELECT count (*) FROM [WorkflowTotals01] where [E1] like '%{0}%'".format(sys.argv[1])
```

Set

```
blah = "hello"
query = "SELECT count (*) FROM [WorkflowTotals01] where [E1] like '%{0}%'".format(blah)
```

Set from a List

```
query = "SELECT count (*) FROM [WorkflowTotals01] where [E1] like '%{0}%'".format(list[0])
```